# I am working on client end development after backend but i am getting an error ETIMEDOUT but backend is working fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/product from localhost:3000 to http://192.168.0.106:4000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ETIMEDOUT).
```

Comment: You must be using a proxy server for development purposes. Could you show it's configuration. 192.168.x.x ip address mentioned in the error is not the one where your backend listensfor connections.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.